# Getting information about the screen status

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, background-task

I'm working on a UWP app which makes use of background task (15 minute interval). This background task downloads certain files, set files as lockscreen/wallpaper and add log entries to log files.

This is all working fine, but whenever the screen goes off (Windows 10), the background task seems to have some trouble with moving files, writing records to database(sqlite), writing stuff to the settings.dat and writing log entries. (As you can see writing to files seems to be a big issue. Something on which I heavily rely on to keep track of certain things)

The only way of solving this seems to me is to check if the screen/power is on. When it's on, proceed with the task. If it's off, don't fire the background task. I've searched the web for a API call which can tell me whether the screen is off or on but couldn't find it. Maybe someone could help me?

I also tried something with "SystemTriggerType.UserAway" but couldn't figure it out. (Got it already running but I don't know how to fire it)

Comment: Would you please try to add a condition to your background task? Like `SystemConditionType.UserPresent`, be aware that `SystemTriggerType.UserPresent` is trigger, not condition. You can refer to [Set conditions for running a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/set-conditions-for-running-a-background-task).

Comment: That's something to play with. Thanks